# Can the network confirm a utxo is from a wallet on a verified list

Tags: transactions, utxo, utxo-committments

Given a business requirement of a verified list of wallets that the network has agreed on. can the network confirm a new type of utxo is from a wallet on this list and reject the new type of utxo if not on this list? While still letting the network manage normal utxo's as usual.

Is this possible given the proper modification to a clone coin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be possible with the cooperation of miners. Miners decide which transactions to include in their blocks, and which to ignore. Currently, this is largely done based on the feerate.

If you have the support of all miners, you could effectively operate a whitelist-only network. If even one miner rejects your proposal, they will continue mining blocks which contain all transactions.

You could fork the Bitcoin Protocol to include a whitelist, but no one would use it.

Comment: Could you elaborate a possible simple example of this in c++. I'm trying to try a prototype idea to see if I can make a whitelist utxo that is different than a normal utxo but don't know where to begin

Comment: I'm afraid level of change is far outside the scope of this site, you would likely want to find a partner familiar with the development side of this space, or hire someone to build it for you

Comment: Do you have links to good places to get more information on this along with finding people who work on this stuff?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't; I usually write my own code for this stuff

Comment: Any way I can dm you to pick your brain on these subjects

Comment: We can move this to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100458/discussion-between-raghav-sood-and-patrick-w-mcmahon).